# Unittesting Mock/Overwriting socket's sendto

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

**[EDIT: The problem only exists with Python 2.7. With 3.7 it works as expected. Any idea what the difference could be and if it's possible to make it work also with 2.7, which I have to use for some reasons]**

I want to overwrite socket's method `sendto` using Mock. My first approach was like this:

```
class TestClass01(TestCase):
    @mock.patch.object(socket.socket, "sendto", new=mock_sendto)
    def test_function1(self):
        ...
```

However, that caused an exception:

> AttributeError: '_socketobject' object attribute 'sendto' is read-only.

This approach has worked fine for other classes but not socket. I take it, the reason is `__init__` calling setattr for all member functions like this:

```
def __init__(self, family=AF_INET, type=SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, _sock=None):
    if _sock is None:
        _sock = _realsocket(family, type, proto)
    self._sock = _sock
    for method in _delegate_methods:
        setattr(self, method, getattr(_sock, method))      <<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

Then, I tried another approach:

```
class TestClass01(TestCase):
    @mock.patch("socket.socket")
    def test_function1(self, mock_class):
        s = mock.Mock(socket.socket)
        s.sendto = mock_sendto
        s.close = mock_close

        mock_class.return_value = s

        # ... run my tests here ...

        args, kwargs = mock_class.call_args_list[0]

        # Check arguments passed to sendto
```

That works, however, the list of call arguments gives me just:

```
((2, 2), {})
```

Which corresponds to the constructor `AF_INET=2` and `SOCK_DGRAM=2`. There is no trace of my call of `sendto`. My workaround was using global variables, which I set from my `mock_sendto` function. Not very elegant, though.

I've got three questions:

1. Could I work around the "read-only" problem and get the initial approach to work?
2. Why does `all_args_list` track only the call of the construction but not of sendto?
3. Is there a better approach than using global variables?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: My high level recommendation is to avoid mocking the `socket` class at all. Instead, just create a loopback or Unix domain socket and let the SUT control one side and your test fixture the other. In my experience it makes the test much easier to write and generally more robust at catching actual problems.

Comment: I hear you, Daniel. I'll certainly consider such an approach. In my specific use case, though, it may be difficult to implement the unit test in this way. That's why I'd like to make it work in Python 2.7.